# In R what's the difference between [[X]] and [, X] when selecting vectors

Tags: r, vector, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
df0 <- data.frame(col1 = c(5, 2), col2 = c(6, 4))
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(5, 2), 
                  col2 = c(6, 4),
                  col3 = ifelse(apply(df0[, 1:2], 1, sum) > 10 & 
                                  df0[, 2] > 5, 
                                "True",
                                "False"))
df2 <- as_tibble(df1)
```

I've got my data frame `df1` above. I've basically "copied" it as a tibble `df2`. Let's mimic an analysis for this `df1` data frame and `df2` tibble.

```
identical(df1[[2]], df1[, 2])
# [1] TRUE
identical(df2[[2]], df2[, 2])
# [1] FALSE
```

Since `df1` and `df2` are essentially the "same", why do I get the TRUE/FALSE dichotomy in my code block above. What is the `tibble()` property that has changed?

The same question asked another way - what is the difference between `[[X]]` and `[, X]`, when applied to base R, and also when used in the tidyverse?

Comment: All lists are vectors but not all vectors are lists. Now if you think of list subsetting, then `df1[[2]]
df1[,2]` should be clear.

Comment: Keep in mind that `[[` and `[` are generic functions. Classes in R are free to decide how they want to respond to those calls. `data.frames` and `tibbles` can do different things. There's no real way to answer this for all objects in R. For example: `x <- structure(1, class="hello"); \`[[.hello\` <- function(x, ...) {"hello"}; x[[1]]; x[[100]]`. So perhaps you as just talking about `data.frames` and `tibbles` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all lists are vectors, we can think of this in terms of list subsetting. Take for instance:

```
L <- list(A = c(1, 2), B = c(1, 4))
L[[2]]
```

This `Extract`s the second element of the list. Extrapolate this to:

```
df1[[2]]
```

We get the same output as `df1[, 2]` hence `identical(df1[[2]], df1[, 2])` returns `TRUE`.
The second part is to do with `tibble` structure ie:

```
typeof(as_tibble(df1)[[2]])
[1] "double"
typeof(as_tibble(df1[, 2]))
[1] "list"
```

The second is a `list` while the `first` is a vector hence `identical` returns `FALSE`.

**Objects of class tbl_df have:**(From the docs)

A class attribute of `c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")`.

**A base type of "list", where each element of the list has the same NROW().**

A names attribute that is a character vector the same length as the underlying list.

A row.names attribute, included for compatibility with the base data.frame class. This attribute is only consulted to query the number of rows, any row names that might be stored there are ignored by most tibble methods.